# Is it appropriate to say that my birthday comes (or arrives) in May?

Tags: word-usage

Is it appropriate to say that my birthday comes (or arrives) in May, Or Christmas comes in December? Which other alternative can I use instead of *comes* or *arrives*?

Could I also say, "my birthday 'falls' in the summer season"?

Answer (score 2):

Using *comes* in that way will be understood, but it is far from idiomatic. The most usual way is just to use an appropriate for of *to be*:

> My birthday **is** in May.

(It's not, but what the hell)

Sometimes, like if it was recent and you're highlighting the fact that it will be a while until it comes again, you would use the past tense.

> Easter **was** in March.

***Falls*** can be more idiomatic, but ***is*** is still safer. *Arrives* should not be used in such situations - it will be understood, but seem very strange.